# How to add shell script to path on mac os?

Tags: java, macos, bash, jar, path

I have such folder structure

```
/Users/alex/Desktop/app/bin/myscript.sh
/Users/alex/Desktop/app/lib/app.jar
```

And the script

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar ../lib/app.jar '@'
```

I try to add the script to PATH:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/alex/Desktop/app/bin
```

And it's ok. But when I execute myscript.sh I get this error

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile ../lib/app.jar
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: use absolute pathes perhaps

Comment: Ok. And what is the best way to store jar for such kind of situations?

Comment: I agree with using absolute paths however I wanted to comment on the storage of such things on the Desktop.  In some circles it consider a poor practice and executables and binaries should be stored in a more proper location, e.g. `$HOME/bin` is better then the Desktop if it's just for your personal use.  Obviously to each their own although I see Users accidentally deleting things they need while cleaning up their Desktop far to often.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
java -jar $( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )/../lib/app.jar '@'
```

But I don't know it this work on MACOSX